# Как оповестить юзера что он заблокирован Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Мне нужно чтобы мой бот блокировал юзера, но когда юзер пишет, бот отвечает "Вы были заблокированы администратором, если вы считаете что блокировка случайная и т.п. пишите сюда: @svelllll".
Обыскал весь интернет, не нашел, находит только как заблокировать пользователя что тоже самое что и черный список.

Comment: А каким образом у вас реализован бан?

Comment: пока никаким .-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так кидайте ID забаненого в список и пусть бот проверяет каждого кто пишет:

```
ban_list = [iD_for_ban]
async def send_help(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id in ban_list:
        await message.reply('Вы забанены пишите сюда @svelllll')
```

Comment: Плюс можно этот список в бд сохранять.

Comment: о, спасибо большое